# Training Yolov5 on RTX 3060 Ti GPU I'm getting error "RuntimeError: Unable to find a valid cuDNN algorithm to run convolution"

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

Training Yolov5 with --img 8088  and batch size 16 on RTX 3060 Ti GPU using the following command

**python train.py --img 1088 --batch 16 --epochs 3 --data coco128.yaml --weights yolov5s.pt --device 0 --workers 0**

I'm getting the following exception "RuntimeError: Unable to find a valid cuDNN algorithm to run convolution" and by reducing the batch size to 8 I'm able to train the model

```
 File "train.py", line 611, in <module>
    main(opt)
  File "train.py", line 509, in main
    train(opt.hyp, opt, device)
  File "train.py", line 311, in train
    pred = model(imgs)  # forward
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hamza.m\workspace\yolov5\models\yolo.py", line 123, in forward
    return self.forward_once(x, profile, visualize)  # single-scale inference, train
  File "C:\Users\hamza.m\workspace\yolov5\models\yolo.py", line 155, in forward_once
    x = m(x)  # run
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hamza.m\workspace\yolov5\models\common.py", line 137, in forward
    return self.cv3(torch.cat((self.m(self.cv1(x)), self.cv2(x)), dim=1))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\hamza.m\workspace\yolov5\models\common.py", line 45, in forward
    return self.act(self.bn(self.conv(x)))
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 727, in _call_impl
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 423, in forward
    return self._conv_forward(input, self.weight)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\conv.py", line 419, in _conv_forward
    return F.conv2d(input, weight, self.bias, self.stride,
RuntimeError: Unable to find a valid cuDNN algorithm to run convolution
```

P.S also can anyone guide me on how to evaluate which GPU is best for training my model please do enlighten me on that as well

Comment: For the second case, try setting batch size to 4 just to make sure that the training can run. 8Gb of memory is really very tight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is on the error log

RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 100.00 MiB (GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 5.48 GiB already allocated; 81.94 MiB free; 5.61 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

It is trying to allocate more memory than you have on your GPU.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reduce the batch_size, I had the same problem and when I reduce the batch size, it works for me !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).